# How can implement the function as asynchronous in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Let me explain my issue. I have a foreach loop and a switch condition inside it. In every switch case, I have concat the results in to a global array.

```
var resultArray = [];
Panels.forEach(function (panel, index) {
 switch( panel.CategoryId ){
   case 'math': 
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
   break;
   case 'physics': 
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
   break;
   case 'zoology': 
      resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
   break;
 }

 return resultArray;
})
```

But the output doesn't contain the values from all cases. I know its because of the asynchronous nature of nodejs. But how can we implement this function in to asynchronous?

Any ideas would be appreciable

Comment: Is the query performed before or after switch condition?

Comment: @MatteoRubini Query performed inside the case condition

Answer (score 0):

To create a similar-sync program flow you must use a callback pattern in your design:

```
functionPerformingQuery(function(result){
    handleResult(result);
});
```

main-idea is:

> - create a function accepting a callback-function
> - call the callback-function when operation is completed
> - define callback-function inside your code to access all private variables

more standardized method is promise()

https://www.promisejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

in the foreach loop, there is no need in return. try it:
    
     `var resultArray = [];
     Panels.forEach(function (panel, index) {
       switch( panel.CategoryId ){
         case 'math': 
           resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
           break;
         case 'physics': 
           resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
           break;
         case 'zoology': 
           resultArray = resultArray.concat(SOMEVALUE COMES FROM DB);
           break;
         }
      })
      console.log(resultArray);`

Answer (score 0):

on my opinion, cuz the request on db is async, you need perform the result using a promise [Jquery Promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
var resultArray = [];
Panels.forEach(function (panel, index) {
 switch( panel.CategoryId ){
   case 'math': 
      myDBfunction().then(function(result) {
         resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
      });
   break;
   case 'physics': 
      myDBfunction().then(function(result) {
         resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
      });
   break;
   case 'zoology': 
      myDBfunction().then(function(result) {
         resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
      });
   break;
 }

 return resultArray;
})

function myDBfunction() {

    var deferred = new jQuery.Deferred();

    // do some with DB (not real code)
    mysql.query("SELECT * ....", function(dbError, dbResult) {
      deferred.resolve(dbResult);
    })

  return deferred.promise()
}
```